# R output of function to environment within function

Tags: r

I'm writing a plugin for Rcmdr, i want to save the output from a function to an object in the current environment.

In R to save the output of a function to an object in the environment given a functiontest():

```
functiontest() <- function() {
object <- c("2","3")

print(object)
}


my_object <- functiontest()
```

If i write in my terminal only functiontest() the console returns the output but it doesn't create in my workspace an object called my_object.

Is there a way i can implement a function that when called create and store permanently an object in the environment? I want to write only in my console

```
functiontest()
```

and automatically store an object in my environment with the output of that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one commenter said, you can "assign" the value to a variable within the global environment. Here's a minimal example:

```
 functiontest <- function(value, name) {
 x <- value
 assign(name, x)
 }
```

Or, using your revised example, this should give you the functionality you need.

```
functiontest <- function() {
  object <<- c("2","3")
  object
}

functiontest()
```

Comment: I believe this would work:         object <<- c("2","3")

Comment: I added a code snippet to my original response. Notice that I removed the parentheses where the function is defined as this will create an error. Derek

Comment: Thanks that's what i wanted

Comment: You can also specify to which environment to save the object: assign("a", a, envir = globalenv()) because <<- will save to an environment one-up from the current (which in this case is the global env anyway).